# Difference between Excel's RAND(), RAND()*RAND(), etc 

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, monte-carlo, excel, central-limit-theorem

I plotted below the standarized results of:

- RAND()
- RAND() * RAND()
- ...
- RAND() * RAND()  * RAND() * RAND()  * RAND() * RAND()

It seems that the results are getting to zero, is that because you're multiplying a bunch of numbers close to zero together, or is there another explanation?
[image]

**EDIT**

There is no real motivation behind this. Working on a spreadsheet earlier today, I was in a situation where i was multiplying a constant * Rand() * Rand() .. each rand() corresponded to a different variable (column), so I wanted to find out what goes on if you multiply a bunch of random numbers together.

Comment: Since MS-Excel's Rand() gives a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1, how did you get ranges from almost -2 to almost 4?

Comment: It seems dassouki standardized the distributions, and that is why it ranges between -2 to 4.

Comment: Since their is some confusion over what we are seeing can you state how you standardized the distributions and why you standardized the distributions? Also some greater context as to your motivation might be nice although not necessary.

Comment: Yes as Andy said. Isn't that what I was supposed to do ?

Comment: I don't know what you are _supoposed_ to do, because I don't kow what you are _trying_ to do. That is why others suggested explaining the motivation...

Comment: What I can say, is that you are reporting a plot and some code (i.e. the rand()*rand()...), but the code you supplied can not possibly create the plot you display. In other words, you need to supply more details in order to get useful help.

Comment: @PeterR: The plots are histograms of simulations (with fairly small numbers of iterations) and they have been standardized to zero mean and unit variance.  The graphic's title says all of this!  The presentation really is quite clear IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standardization is good, but it's not the right standardization for this situation.  It helps to see that multiplying values of RAND() is the same as adding their logarithms (followed by a subsequent exponentiation).  Because the different calls to RAND() are supposed to be independent, those logarithms are still independently distributed.  As a simple calculation shows, their common distribution actually has a mean and variance.  (In fact, its negative is an exponential distribution.)  The Central Limit Theorem applies.  It says that the *logs*, suitably standardized, converge to a normal distribution.  We conclude that these products--standardized to have a constant *geometric* mean and constant *geometric* variance--are converging to the exponential of a normally distributed variable: that is, a [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Answer (score 6):

> In Excel, the Rand function returns a random number that is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1. The Rand function returns a new random number each time your spreadsheet recalculates.

[[source](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rand.php)]

Because RAND() is always less than one and greater than zero, multiplying it by itself will make it smaller. As you do that over and over, you will get closer to zero. If you want something that gives you a random number between 0 and a, you can do a*RAND() instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why your graph has values from -2 to 4 but for what it is worth here is the answer to the text of your question:

Suppose that $U \sim U[0,1]$. Then the cdf of $U$ is given by $F(u) = u$ for $u \in (0,1)$ and 1 otherwise.

When you multiply different iid realizations of the random draws you are essentially computing the following:

$Y = U^n$ where $n$ is the number of times you are multiplying the random draws.

Thus, the corresponding cdf is:

$F(y) = P(Y \le y)$

i.e.,

$F(y) = P(U^n \le y)$

i.e.,

$F(y) = P(U \le y^{1/n})$

i.e.,

$F(y) = y^{1/n}$ for $y \in (0,1)$ and 1 otherwise.

The above cdf of $Y$ converges to a [dirac-delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function on $Y=0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, $E(y) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

The above convergence is also related to [first-order stochastic dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order_stochastic_dominance) in the following sense:

Suppose that $n_1 > n_2$. Then, it is the case that:

$F(y|n_1) \ge F(y|n_2)$

Intuitively, the above result states that: In visual terms as $n$ increases the cdf of $Y$ shifts to the right. This happens because the pdf associated with $Y$ starts concentrating at the lower end of the interval $[0,1]$ and asymptotically all the pdf concentrates at 0 which explains the observed behavior.

**General Case**

@whuber's comment to this answer gives the solution when $Y$ is the product of $n$ independent, *different* random variables drawn from [0,1].

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. U^n corresponds to multiplying the *same* random value by itself n times. dassouki's procedure will multiply n *different* random values. As an example, the product distribution of two standard normal r.v.'s is *not* chi-squared on 2 d.f : http://dx.doi.org/10.1137%2F0118065

Comment: @onestop hmm your are right but I think the reasoning carries over to the general case. I will think about it and fix the answer.

Comment: @Srikant: The conclusion about convergence to a delta function isn't terribly useful or insightful.  (Analogously, if one weren't to adopt the right standardization of sums of random variables, the CLT would vanish into thin air: you would often just conclude that the sums "converge" to an improper uniform distribution over all the reals!)  A better way to investigate such phenomena is to seek some standardization that assures convergence to something non-trivial if that is at all possible.

Comment: @Srikant: The distribution of the product of n uniforms is the exponential of a (negated) Gamma(n) variate.

Comment: @whuber You are correct about standardization but I did not interpret the question that way (or at least it was not clear from the question context that the OP wanted to know the behavior of the product of different standardized uniform random variates. Thanks for the pointer on the product of n uniforms. I will update the answer to reflect that info.

Comment: @Srikant: Yes, there's always opportunity for multiple interpretations.  I took the OP's careful investigation, including the standardization and graphing, as an indication of a deeper and more sophisticated perception of the phenomenon than just being something "getting to zero" or converging to a delta distribution.  The ultimate arbiter of the question's intent is its proposer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mysterious reason. If you multiply a bunch of numbers between 0 an 1, the result will forcibly be close to 0. The average result for RAND()*RAND()*RAND()*RAND()*RAND()*RAND() should be something close to (0.5^6), that is, 0.015625.

Be careful using Excel's RAND() function, though. It's not the best random number generator in the world.

Comment: Excel's RAND() is the worst pseudo RNG I have ever measured.  (I applied the DieHard tests to it about ten years ago.)  It's not even equidistributed!  Nevertheless, it's OK for this kind of investigation.