# Asymptotic behavior of $\prod_{i=1}^s (1-\alpha x^2_i)^2$ for Gaussian $x_i$

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Suppose $x_i$ comes from standard Normal. For a given $\alpha$, I'm interested the following random variable:

$$f(s)=\log \prod_{i=1}^s (1-\alpha x^2_i)^2$$

For $\alpha=2.422$, empirical distribution of $f(100)$ [looks](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-variance-multiplicative.nb) like this:

[image]

- What kind of distribution is it?
- How do I estimate the variance in the limit of large $s$?

**Edit** regarding suggestions to apply Central Limit Theorem, I'm unsure whether the conditions for CLT are satisfied here. A [tutorial](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eredner/pubs/pdf/ajp58p267.pdf) suggests that we can't take logs and apply CLT:

[image]

Motivation: this describes behavior of LMS filter for Gaussian observations. Related [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87091/for-which-values-of-step-size-is-lms-filter-stable) on dsp.SE

Comment: Expand the log of the product to a sum, and apply the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)

Comment: I see....I was a bit confused by this [tutorial](http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/pubs/pdf/ajp58p267.pdf) which at end of Section II says that "there's no analog of a central limit theorem for a random multiplicative process"

Comment: Notice that in order to calculate the variance you don't need to rely on asymptotic behavior,  but just to know the variance of $\log(1-\alpha x^2)$

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3707.